# How only select max row in sqlite?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I has 1 Table data ex:

```
 A  B   C   D

100 1   1   1
100 2   1   0
```

Key: Columns A and B

My Sql:

```
select *,max(B) from Table where D=1 group by A
```

Result : Row 1

I only want select Row 2. If Row 2 has D=0 ,Result is null.

or this data: i want get row 4 and row 5 has: max(B) and D=1

```
   A    B   C   D

    100 1   1   1
    100 2   1   0
    101 1   1   1
    101 2   1   1
    102 1   1   1
```

How only select max row in sqlite? Thanks all.

Comment: Please provide a larger data set and the expected result. Your criteria for `max` is not clear.

Comment: i had updated my question

Comment: Please post the actual result the way you want to see if.

Comment: AT: or this data: i want get row 4 and row 5 has: max(B) and D=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (B,A) IN
    (SELECT max(B),A
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY A
     )
    AND D=1;
```

Comment: GROUP BY A HAVING D=1

Comment: row 2 still output in result

Comment: row 2 not output OK, but row 1,row 3 still output in result

Comment: which is your expected row?

Comment: Only get row 4 and row 5 (AT: or this data: i want get row 4 and row 5 has: max(B) and D=1)

Comment: In row5 where max(B)?

Comment: A= 102 has max(B) =1 , We group by A.

Comment: Then why you first row not expect?

Comment: A=100 has max(B)=2, Row 1: A=100  has B=1

Comment: the same : row 1 and row 3 still output

Comment: Is (B,A)  connect String?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this query can help you:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1,
(select max(B) MB,max(A) MA from table1)t2
where (t1.A = t2.MA or t1.B = t2.MB) and
t1.D = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0b691/2)

Comment: Specially it shows row `5` take a look at `SQL Fiddle` link to see the answer.